# Can someone approve this edit?

Tags: discussion

This edit was rejected(huh?), can someone approve it? Submitter is an Ubuntu Core Dev and is a fix (installing linux-generic instead of linux-image)

- https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/243019

Comment: Is it even possible? @mods

Comment: Thinking about this again (I was one to reject the suggest): Why didn't he post his own answer - or write a comment? Edits should not change the essential meaning of the original post, should they? (I felt some pain when you said "huh?" )

Comment: The edit fixed a command, from `linux-image-generic-lts-quantal` to `linux-generic-lts-quantal`. The other part is just reiterating the support statements of the HWE stack. Information like that shouldn't be in a comment since it's useful, and fixing answers is what the site is about!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An already rejected edit can't be rolled back nor undo:

> There is no undo at the moment, I always planned to have undo gmail style. But we have resisted complexity here. Once you have undo, you have to add a slew of checks prior to undoing.
>
> On SO the community will pick up and approve if you just made a mistake. *On other sites, you can go and manually apply the edit if this was an honest mistake.*

I've just applied manually the edit.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88098/213575