# Should I approve edits like this?

Tags: discussion

I was shown [this edit to review](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/573790).

It's a nice edit, sure. But it also adds a ton of stuff the OP don't put in.

Should I approve or reject such edits?

Comment: Reject, that is an `attempt to reply` it is very rare adding a massive block of text like that is a good thing. It should be suggested in a comment below or an answer it's self. Of course, that is my opinion, the results show Eric Carvalho thought is was OK.

Comment: @MarkKirby So then what happened over here? http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8848/can-someone-approve-this-edit?rq=1

Comment: That is Jorges opinion, I never approve these large block of text edits but that is why it takes multiple users to approve or reject it, we are all subject to our personal preferences and opinions. I think it adds so much information, it could be an answer all of its own but that is just my opinion.

Comment: @MarkKirby - Interesting. looks like Eric Carvalho (25k user) approved, while you & I rejected.

Comment: Don't think to hard about it and a users rep has nothing to do with it. Yes higher rep users have more experience (generally) but every one is subject to making mistakes. Just go with what you think is correct, there is no `correct` way to review everything, it is your vote, use it as you see fit.

Comment: @MarkKirby -You've been really helpful getting me started here :)

Comment: @MarkKirby In a way it does have something to do with rep. Your first comment you mentioned that this should be in a comment and unfortunately you cannot comment until you reach 50 rep.

Comment: @proprocastinator Why do you keep posting these comments to me? You seem to have misunderstood this in some way, I was referring to users opinions on the edits, not the editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO that wasn't an attempt to reply. It was legitimate attempt to add to the answer (each paragraph was about a problem with unencrypted traffic). However, I'd have agreed with the rejection, but only because it added too much. It should have been in an answer of its own.